# random variable probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I am trying to find the answer to a mathematical probability problem.
let a box contain $5$ balls : $2$ balls white, $2$ balls green, and $1$ red ball (we can't differentiate between the balls by touching so to have equal probability chances ).
Now, We pull successively and after that we return the balls, $3$ balls from the box.

1- let $A$ be the event of "pulling $3$ balls with the same color".
prove that : $$P(A)=\frac{17}{125}$$ 
Now let $X$ be the Random variable that is equal to the number of White balls pulled

2- determine the law of probability of the Random Variable $X$.

For the First question it's pretty easy, 
we have the $$Cardw=n^{p}=5^{3}=125$$

$$CardA=2^{3}+2^{3}+1^{3}=17$$

so we have $$P(A)=\frac{17}{125}$$ 
but we the second question I am stuck , can u help me

Answer (score 1):

Call pulling a white ball a "success." We are repeating an experiment independently $3$ times, where each time the probability of success is $2/5$.

The random variable $X$ gives the number of successes in $3$ independent trials. Thus $X$ has **binomial distribution**, parameters $n=3$, $p=2/5$.

For $k=0,1,2,3$, we have
$$\Pr(X=k)=\binom{3}{k}(2/5)^k(3/5)^{3-k}.$$